# SSRS How can I freeze columns and rows of a matrix inside of a list

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-tablix

My SSRS report that currently works as expected uses a matrix and I am freezing the columns and rows by using the tablix properties "Keep header visible while scrolling." Now I need to separate the data onto different pages by 'EventId.' To do that, I put the matrix inside of a list and set the list to group on EventId. After putting the matrix inside of the list, I get the error message

> "The tablix includes a table header or column with fixedheader set to
>   true. this is not allowed on data regions inside other data regions"

How can I freeze columns and rows of a matrix inside of a list? Or is there another way that I can group the related data for a specific EventId on a different page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another level of grouping to your current matrix to group the Event IDs and break between them.

Keep your matrix and get rid of the List.

Add a new Parent Group to your matrix's current detail group, Grouping by `EventId`.

Delete the new column, but select `Delete Columns Only` so the grouping remains.

On the new EventId Group's BreakLocation properties, select `Between` to have create a new page for each event ID.

[image]

Comment: The page break works, but it's not breaking at the right place. Here is what the report is supposed to look like https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qDJ3AzjH6av-tW5WI5x9rIXmgB-BaJg0. It should look like that for each EventId. I added a parent group like this https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EQQLiFl6Zw-ZR5RGrqUObqvw5BS6LGGO and here is what it looks like after https://drive.google.com/open?id=10hARvjhEHt0ph-VG4x3e5iM6TQlgmtrJ

Comment: I tried adding the EventId group to the parent of PerformanceDescription group also, but that didn't produce the expected results either because of the bottom 2 rows that are not apart of the group

Comment: I didn't see that you are working with two groups. You'll need the Parent Group to be over **both** your sub-groups. I'm not sure how to get there from where you are now - you may need to start your table over. Create the parent group first then create the second grouping inside the parent. When correct, the left "parenthesis" to the left of Requirement Description should also go down and include the Performance Description row group.

Comment: The grouping should look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ULRn.png

Comment: Not sure if it's going to work in my situation yet, but you did answer the question so I am going to mark it as answered. I will reply if I have any issues.

Comment: You can create a Group inside the parent by and ADD GROUP -> ADJACENT AFTER on the Requirement_Description row group. Then copy the row from the below group and paste in the new one.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KAKGrf37c54pKvElhaSiHE7WSR5msXQu It's working now. The only issue now is with the column group. All of the columns are displayed on each page, rather than just the ones for that EventId https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OiuI9c3K0YQwRVz15HEU-DS7Abwkx_Vq

Comment: @KRob - err - I didn't realize that they had different columns for each Event ID. Because it's all in one table, it's adding all of the column groups. I don't see a way around this, though.

Comment: Ya, I just realized that in the 2nd screenshot from my last comment, the performance description field is returning the same row. So I guess I am going to have to redesign the report or just tell them we can't freeze it. I should be able to use that neat trick you taught me in the future though, so thank you.